Derivation of Spherical Aberration at Single Spherical Surface

My lecture note has the derivation of refraction at single spherical surface, but a bit more quantitatively done. It derives a more accurate expression for the focal length:
$$ f = R \left[ \frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{h^2}{2n(n-1)R^2} \right] $$
I understand this $f$ derivation but it then directly writes the derived imaging equation for a single spherical surface:
$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{n}{b} = \frac{n-1}{R} + h^2 \left[ \frac{1}{2a} \left( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{R} \right) ^2 + \frac{n}{2b} \left( \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{b} \right) ^2 \right] $$
The $a$ in the second equation is the object distance and $b$ is the image distance (I think). I have no idea how you can derive this equation.
